# aws ec2 create-tags with quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I can't seem to create a tag on a resource if the value contains a quote. For example:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resource $someResource --tags 'Key=mykey,Value={"json":"value"}'
```

fails with:

```
Error parsing parameter '--tags': should be: Key value pairs, with multiple values separated by a space.
```

But if I run it without the quotes in the value, it succeeds:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resource $someResource --tags 'Key=mykey,Value={json:value}'
```

I've tried a few different combinations of quoting/escaping, but I just can't seem to set the JSON value from the CLI.

For completeness, I updated my tools yesterday:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.3.6 Python/2.7.5 Darwin/13.1.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Negative, this is from a Mac running 10.9.2

Comment: In a similar environment (OSX, Python 2.7, aws-cli 1.3.7), I can use the JSON syntax this way: `aws ec2 create-tags --resource $someResource --tags '{"Key":"myKey","Value":"myvalue"}'` Does it answer your question? I'm not sure how you want to use JSON...

Comment: I believe this issue is more general, in that you can't have a double-quote in the value from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Bumped into the same problem, and found a way to circumvent this unexpected behaviour I think:

`aws ec2 create-tags --resource $someResource --tags Key=mykey,Value='"{\"json\":\"value\"}"'`

A bit overdue maybe, but someone might find it useful. The matter is that the awscli seems to try to parse what's inside the quotes to a variable, and if it is not default to a string, it will give an error. So within the quotes, another set of quotes needs to be used, so that it will default to a string.

Comment: This didn't directly solve the issue that I was having, but it lead to it.  I already had some escaped quotes ( \" ) in the string that I was needing to pass.  I doubly escaped them with ( \\\") and it worked for me.  I was AWS CLI to call SQS.